# Log latest commit from current branch (even if master)

Tags: git

`git log master.. -1` lists the last commit of the currently checked out branch. Unfortunately, it does not work if `master` itself is checked out.

I'm wondering if there's a command that also works on `master`.

Comment: `git log HEAD` should do.

Comment: `git log -1` will work. @FelixKling your suggestion is just showing log from the HEAD it's quite similar

Comment: @FelixKling looks good, why don't you "answer"? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is

```
git log -1
```

since the "since..until" arguments are missing, it defaults to HEAD which is the last commit most of the times. the `-[n]` is the quantity of commit to show. Since we are looking from the last commit, we only show 1 commit log.

It will work on any branch because you're not specifying any branch. HEAD is always the commit you're working from.

If you want more information, I'd recommend reading the manual.

```
man git-log
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought `git log -1` logs the latest commit in the graph, no matter which branch is checked out. After testing again, this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

i am not totally sure what you want, but maybe `git show`